# Is it ok to create a variable as a shortcut for multiple accesses of same object property?

Tags: android, variables, naming

Let's say I have this piece of code in an android project:

```
center.x = (int) (binding.trainingActivityFixationPoint.getX() + 
binding.trainingActivityFixationPoint.getWidth() / 2);

center.y = (int) (binding.trainingActivityFixationPoint.getY() + 
binding.trainingActivityFixationPoint.getHeight() / 2);
```

Technically, accessing trainingActivityFixationPoint repeatedly should be a constant operation as it is already cached in the android binding object so I think this does not warrant creating a variable in itself, however the length of above accesses appears cluttering to me. Is it better in such cases to introduce a new variable and have the code look like this?:

```
ImageView fixation = binding.trainingActivityFixationPoint;
center.x = (int) (fixation.getX() + fixation.getWidth() / 2);
center.y = (int) (fixation.getY() + fixation.getHeight() / 2);
```

I have found myself doing this quite often with android but I not sure if this is a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this - it's simply a reference to an existing object.  Keep in mind though, that if this reference does not go out of scope, the entire object referenced by binding will not be garbage collected.

If you are using fixation inside a method, for example, it's scoped and not an issue at all. References like this are very small and as long as you do not create thousands, have no measurable impact on your application.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that's what I thought also; just needed some reassurance that what I was doing is fine.

Comment: Good stuff - at the end of the day, readability and clarity trumps almost everything else.